# JS not working when user is a reader

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have a JS that displays something in a page,
when I login as a Reader, it doesnt display anything (when I debug the JS using IE Dev tools, it runs but ends at some point)

But when I login as a contributor or higher, the JS code performs well.

The JS is in my SiteAssets and I tried moving it to Style Library and publishing it and still the same, I also moved it to Layouts and still the same.

Comment: Can you please post your JS code? If not then can you write what its doing? Also what do you mean by `ends at some point` does it throws any error or something else? You will have to provide some more information.

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: `$j(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(test, "SP.js");
});

function test() {
    processRefiners();
    
}


function processRefiners() {

    var refDiv = $j('#Refiner').html();
    $j('#Refiner').append("");
    $j('#RefinerPanel').html(refDiv);

    $j('#searchBar').show();

}`

basically the code just appends some checkboxes and texts into a div

Comment: Why would people vote down my question, as if they know everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `executeFunc` instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`

Answer (score 1):

Though you should write the JS code here but I can safely assume that your JS is accessing some list on which the user don't have permission. It's not about the permission on JS file it's al about the permission on the resources your JS file is trying to access.

Comment: Agree with Taran. See if you are writing any CSOM code to fetch data from lists.

Comment: In my masterpage, there is a div that is hidden `style="display:none"` and in the JS, this is being shown by the JS. Is there an impact here?

Comment: User is able to see masterpage?

Comment: Yes, reader can see the masterpage

Comment: Is there a condition on which it should be visible or hidden?

Comment: None, it is on `display:none` by default.

Comment: I meant the condition to make it visible.

Comment: I went thru the code, and its primary function is justo append DOM in the div.

Also, I created a SharePoint webpart (ascx) with javascript, the function of the javascript is to use the search REST api. and display some results. 

When I login as reader, the webpart wont show me any result, but when I directly use the search REST api and enter it in my browser, it returns the result (xml). This means that my reader can access the search rest api.